# Refreshing DataTables table populated with loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I want to update table content without refreshing the page but I fill the table using a loop on the same page. Here is the code I use:

```
<div id="items_table">
<div class="table-responsive" id="table_allitems">
<table id="products_all" class="table-sm table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
<thead class="table-secondary table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Код</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Име</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Баркод</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Група</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Мярка</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Количество</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Обект</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Доставна цена</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <center>Продажна цена</center>
    </th>
    <th scope="col"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="skladove_table">

 <?php
  $query_checkObekt = "SELECT * FROM obekti WHERE owner='$user_hash'";
  $result_checkObekt = mysqli_query($conn, $query_checkObekt);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result_checkObekt) > 0) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner ='$user_hash'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

            {
              echo '<tr id="' . $row['unique_id'] . '" onmouseover=showItem(' . $row['unique_id'] . ');>';

              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['custom_id'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['name'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['barcode'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['grupa'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['quantity_type'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['quantity_number'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['obekt'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['price_delivery'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . "<center>" . $row['price_sale'] . "</center>" . "</td>";
              echo "<td style='width: 1%; padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;' onclick='deleteItem(" . $row['unique_id'] . ");'><i class='fa fa-close'></i>"."</td>";

              echo "</tr>";
            }

  } else {
    //no records found
  }

  ?>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div><br
```

To add new item I use iframe modal and what I want is after closing the modal or just pressing one button table to get refreshed (and if possible to stay on the same page) with the new info without refreshing the page.

Comment: put your table creation code in a function then call it from either your modal's button or from anywhere, where you want to modify the table and display it.

Comment: There's a thing which was developed for this. We call it ajax :)

Comment: I know Ajax. I also made it with ajax. But I want to know is there a way to refresh the table when not using ajax. :)

Comment: which datatable you are using?

Comment: https://datatables.net/